# Firestore Security rules preventing Listeners

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Having an issue where firestore security rules are blocking my realtime listeners

Here are the security rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      function isAdmin(uid) {
        return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/employees/$(uid)).data["Type"] == "Admin";
      }
      match /transactions/{transactionID} {
        //allow transaction if admin or if the user making the request is the EID of the relevant assignment
        allow read, create: if isAdmin(request.auth.uid) ||
            get(/databases/$(database)/documents/assignments/$(resource.data.assignment)).data.EID == request.auth.uid;
      }
      match /threads/{threadID} {
        allow read, write: if resource.data.Parties[0] == request.auth.uid ||
        resource.data.Parties[1] == request.auth.uid;
      }
      match /sites/{siteID} {
        allow read;
      }
      match /employees/{employeeID} {
        allow read, write: if isAdmin(request.auth.uid) ||
            (employeeID == request.auth.uid)
      }
      match  /employees/{employeeID}/EditHistory {
        allow read, write: if isAdmin(request.auth.uid) ||
            (employeeID == request.auth.uid)
      }
            match /employees/{employeeID}/Sessions {
        allow read, write: if isAdmin(request.auth.uid) ||
            (employeeID == request.auth.uid)
      }
      match /directory/{any} {
        allow read;
      }
      match /assignments/{assignmentID} {
        allow read, write: if isAdmin(request.auth.uid) ||
            get(/databases/$(database)/documents/assignments/$(assignmentID)).data.EID == request.auth.uid;
      }
      match /analytics {
        allow read: if isAdmin(request.auth.uid);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

All of my listeners are being blocked with the error "insufficient permissions", but when I try the corresponding get queries in the security rules playground they're allowed.

Here is an example of the query I'm attempting.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if (user) {

                unsubscribeTimetrackingListener = firebase.firestore().collection('employees').doc(currentUser.uid).collection("Sessions").where("Date", "==", generateDateStr(0))
                    .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
                        fetchHistory();
                    }, (err) => {
                        console.error("Timetracking Listener Error: ", err);
                    })
            }
        });
```

Are there any steps I can take from here to attempt to debug why the listeners are being blocked?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would write your nested security rules as so:

```
     match /employees/{employeeID} {
        allow read, write: if isAdmin(request.auth.uid) ||
            (employeeID == request.auth.uid)

        match  /EditHistory/{history} {
          allow read, write: if isAdmin(request.auth.uid) ||
              (employeeID == request.auth.uid)
        }

        match /Sessions/{session} {
        allow read, write: if isAdmin(request.auth.uid) ||
            (employeeID == request.auth.uid)
        }
      }
```

In general, granting access to documents is SPECIFIC TO THAT LEVEL - it does NOT automatically extend to allow child levels.  The nested rules, above, add access to the nested collections.

You might also write:

```
      match /employees/{employeeID} {
        allow read, write: if isAdmin(request.auth.uid) ||
            (employeeID == request.auth.uid)
      }

      match  /employees/{employeeID}/EditHistory{histories} {
        allow read, write: if isAdmin(request.auth.uid) ||
            (employeeID == request.auth.uid)
      }

            match /employees/{employeeID}/Sessions/{sessions} {
        allow read, write: if isAdmin(request.auth.uid) ||
            (employeeID == request.auth.uid)
      }
```

[note the addition of {histories} and {sessions}]

Comment: I'd check `isAdmin` after checking if the userId matches to allow you to shortcut the database lookups.